# i3lock wallpaper when closing lid

Tags: i3, screen-lock

I'm new to Arch Linux, and I would like to have i3lock with a background of my choice welcoming me after I close the lid of my laptop. However, though I was able to achieve the nice background for both screensaver and manual lock, I always get a black background to i3lock when I suspend by closing the lid. Here is what I put in my `/boot/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
hHandleLidSwitch=lock suspend
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=lock suspend
```

where `lock` is a script, `/bin/lock`:

```
#!/bin/bash
i3lock -i 'path_to_my_picture'
```

I restarted several times `systemd-logind` with `systemctl restart`, but no results. The command `lock` works fine when used directly from the command line.

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The minuscule h in the first line of code is a typo.

Comment: You can edit your post instead of writing a comment like that.